# How-to get JSON array into an other entity with Jackson

Tags: android, arrays, json, jackson, ormlite

I'm currently using the ***`Jackson library`*** into my *Android* application

I'd like to get an json array into an entity but that one is and array of strings like this :

```
"gallery": [
    "URL",        "URL",        "URL",        "",
    "",        "",        "",        "",        "",        "",
    0
  ],
```

I've done from now on this into my *`Parent entity`*:

```
@JsonProperty("gallery")
@DatabaseField
private Collection<String> mGallery;
```

I wanna do this to save the 'sub'-entity to my *`Ormlite`* database.

Does anyone would know how I'm supposed to name my field on the sub-entity ?

Thanks :)